# Is "by" correct in "performing this treatment (by) myself"?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, prepositional-passive

Which is correct, with or without *by*?

- They challenged me to analyze the possibility of performing this treatment **by** myself.
  or:
- They challenged me to analyze the possibility of performing this treatment myself.

This sentence (without *by*) is chosen by an English software and I do not understand why.

Comment: One does not "perform" a treatment. One treats a patient with x. One carries out a treatment. To do something oneself.

Answer (score 1):

(Perform it) **by myself/yourself** etc means without the support or company of anybody else.

**You have to complete the cross-country hike by yourself in order to test your map-reading skills.** (Nobody is allowed to accompany you).

**Perform it myself/yourself/himself/herself/ourselves/themselves** is a phrase used to emphasise the person/s concerned, not necessarily to exclude others.

**If you think it's easy, try it yourself**.
**Everybody was amazed that I managed to fix the computer myself**.
**Because there was no doctor on board the aircraft, the air-crew delivered the baby themselves**.

You might have said that they delivered the baby **by themselves**. This would indicate that nobody else assisted them. They alone did it.

Comment: perform a treatment is not  good. Sorry.

Comment: thank you for your answers. Yes, Lambie, you are right.